# CMake - objects being built twice unnecessarily?

Tags: c++, c, cmake

I have a list of files that need to be compiled for my main executable. My tests also need these files. When the test executable(s) are built, the object files are built again, even though earlier in the build they were built when the main executable was built.

Am I wrong in thinking this is not needed? If so is there a way to disable this?

Example:

```
set(SOURCES
${SOURCE_DIR}/file.c
${SOURCE_DIR}/another_file.c)

set(MAIN ${SOURCE_DIR}/main.c)

add_executable(main_executable ${SOURCES} ${MAIN})

add_executable(test1_ex ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/test/test1.cc ${SOURCES})
```

Comment: Can you post the relevant parts of your makefile?

Comment: If you list the same source file for multiple targets, it will be built once *for each target*.

Comment: CMake will build them twice, because you could have different compiler flags for your main and test executables. You could avoid this by first compiling them to a library, and then linking that library to both your executables.

Comment: @HansPetterTaugbølKragset added example to post

Comment: build an application library. link both the test executable and your main.cpp with the application library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the common code in a library and link the library to both your application and tests.

```
# The application's sources - except main
set(SOURCES
        ${SOURCE_DIR}/file.c
        ${SOURCE_DIR}/another_file.c)

# build an application library
add_library(app_lib ${SOURCES})

# build an executable in terms of the application library
set(MAIN ${SOURCE_DIR}/main.c)
add_executable(main_executable ${MAIN})
target_link_libraries(main_executable PRIVATE app_lib)

# build a test executable in terms of the application library
add_executable(test1_ex ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/test/test1.cc)
target_link_libraries(test1_ex PRIVATE app_lib)
```

Answer (score 1):

This could be due to the following scenario:

```
add_library(mylib1 file1.cpp common.cpp)
add_library(mylib2 file2.cpp common.cpp)
```

That created the same problem you're having for me, where `common.cpp` was being rebuilt for every library. My solution was this:

```
add_library(common_lib common.cpp)
add_library(mylib1 file1.cpp)
add_library(mylib2 file2.cpp)
target_link_libraries(mylib1 common_lib)
target_link_libraries(mylib2 common_lib)
```

That resolved the problem for me as the building (object creation) was done once, but it was linked to every other library.